# SQLITEPROGRAMCODE

Tags: android

> D:\ANDROIDPROJECT\SQL\app\src\main\java\Products.java:5: error:
>    expected
>       private int_id;
>                     ^ D:\ANDROIDPROJECT\SQL\app\src\main\java\Products.java:6: error:
>    expected
>       private String_productname;
>                                 ^ D:\ANDROIDPROJECT\SQL\app\src\main\java\Products.java:14: error:
>    expected public void set_id(int_id)
>                            ^ D:\ANDROIDPROJECT\SQL\app\src\main\java\Products.java:20: error:
>    expected public void set_productname(String_productname)
>                                                 ^ D:\ANDROIDPROJECT\SQL\app\src\main\java\Products.java:29: error: not a
>   statement
>       return_id;
>       ^ D:\ANDROIDPROJECT\SQL\app\src\main\java\Products.java:36: error: not a statement
>       return_productname;

these are the errors in this program below help me to resolve them.

```
public class Products  {

    private int_id;
    private String_productname;
    public Products(String productname)
    {

        this._productname=productname;

    }

public void set_id(int_id)
{
    this._id = _id;


}

public void set_productname(String_productname)
{
    this._productname()=_productname;

}

public int get_id()
{

    return_id;

}

public String get_productname()

{

    return_productname;


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Java code

```
public class Products {

    private int _id;
    private String _productname;

    public Products(String productname){
        this._productname=productname;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) { 
        this._id = _id;
    } 

    public void set_productname(String _productname) { 
        this._productname=_productname;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    } 
    public String get_productname() {
        return _productname;
    }
}
```